# SQL group function nested too deeply

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

I want to make a SQL query which finds the `pname` of parts which are the least repeated in   `supplier_parts_shipment`.

Table 1 supplier (sno, sname, city)

```
1, ahmad, jeddah
2,kaled,med
3,njwa,med
```

Table 2 parts (pno, pname, color)

```
1, laptop, red
2,keybord,blue
```

Table 3 supplier_parts_shipment (shno, sno, pno, date)

```
1,1,1,2014
2,2,1,2014
3,3,2,2014
```

I tried something like this:

```
  SELECT pname 
       , min(count(pno)) 
    FROM parts 
   WHERE pno IN (SELECT pno 
                   FROM supplier_parts_shipment 
                  group by 
                        pname 
                 HAVING min(count(pno))
                )
SQL> /
pno IN(SELECT pno FROM supplier_parts_shipment group by pname HAVING min(count(pno))))
                                                                         *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00935: group function is nested too deeply
```

Answer (score 1):

I would have gone about it in a different manner.

First create a query that shows the counts of shipments by pname ordered in ascending values. Use that as a subquery and pick the first.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(sps.pno), p.pname 
    FROM supplier_parts_shipment sps
    JOIN parts p on sps.pno = p.pno
    GROUP BY pname
    ORDER BY COUNT(sps.pno) ASC)
WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

Comment: Hi, please pay attention to the tags... I've corrected your query so it'll work now.

Comment: @Ben Thank you for the correction. Forgot Oracle doesn't allow `TOP` and such

Comment: SQL> SELECT * FROM (
  2      SELECT COUNT(pno), p.pname 
  3      FROM supplier_parts_shipment 
  4      JOIN parts p on sps.pno = p.p
  5      GROUP BY pname
  6      ORDER BY COUNT(pno) ASC)
  7  WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
    ORDER BY COUNT(pno) ASC)
                   *
ERROR at line 6:
ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

Comment: @user3001575 Response fixed. It needed the table aliases to specify which column

Answer (score 0):

```
min(count(pno))
```

makes no sense. that is why you are getting the error. try:

```
select parts.pname
     , subse.c 
  from (select pno
             , dense_rank() over (order by c asc) r
             , c
          from (select pno
                     , count(pno) as c
                  from supplier_parts_shipment
                 group by
                       pno
               )
       ) subse
 inner join parts
    on (parts.pno = subse.pno)
 where subse.r = 1
```

the innermost select counts the supplier_parts_shipment for pno, the second level finds the pno that has the least count from the innermost. the outermost select then joins pname from parts and filters to the one that has the least repeats.

Comment: ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Comment: i corrected it and tested it. it works now and gives only the parts with the least number of shipped parts

Answer (score 0):

If there are multiple parts which are least frequent and you want all of them then:

```
WITH pno_frequencies AS (
  SELECT pno,
         COUNT(1) AS pno_cnt
  FROM   supplier_parts_shipment
  GROUP BY pno
),
least_frequent_pnos AS (
  SELECT pno
  FROM   pno_frequencies
  WHERE  pno_cnt = ( SELECT MIN( pno_cnt ) FROM pno_frequencies )
)
SELECT pname
FROM   parts p
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   least_frequent_pnos f
               WHERE  p.pno = f.pno
              );
```

If you only want a single part regardless of whether there are multiple parts with the same minimum frequency then:

```
WITH pno_frequencies AS (
  SELECT pno,
         COUNT(1) AS pno_cnt
  FROM   supplier_parts_shipment
  GROUP BY pno
  ORDER BY pno_cnt ASC
),
least_frequent_pno AS (
  SELECT pno
  FROM   pno_frequencies
  WHERE  ROWNUM = 1
)
SELECT pname
FROM   parts p
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   least_frequent_pno f
               WHERE  p.pno = f.pno
              );
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/32810/2/1)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **oracle 12c** or higher then it will be quite easy with `row limiting clause` as following:

```
Select p.pname, count(1) as cnt
From parts p
Join supplier_parts_shipment sps
  On sps.pno = p.pno
Group by p.name
Order by cnt
Fetch first row with ties
```

For more information about row limiting clause refer [this document](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/row-limiting-clause-for-top-n-queries-12cr1).

Cheers!!